# Using ncurses terms is giving me an error

Tags: c++, input, ncurses

I want to continually check for keyboard presses to control a character. After some research i saw people recommended ncurses for mac so I tried this but it did not go well. I made a test to see if it worked but I get the error message "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:". Is there any way I can fix this. (Im just starting with coding so maybe its something really small and dumb).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
halfdelay(1);

int c = getch();

switch (c)
{
case KEY_UP:
cout << endl << "You pressed UP" << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize curses, e.g.,

```
initscr();
```

before the `keypad` call.  The [manual page for ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) mentions this:

> To get character-at-a-time input  without  echoing  (most  interactive,
>          screen  oriented  programs want this), the following sequence should be
>          used:

```
       initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
```

> Most programs would additionally use the sequence:

```
       nonl();
       intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
       keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

Keep in mind that ncurses is a **C** library; including the header tells the compiler *how* to call the functions, but there is very little *code* in the header.  Depending on the configuration, you need a **`-lncurses`** or **`-lncursesw`** linker option to tell the compiler how to link against the library.

Comment: The problem isn't with the code itself (it might be as well butt.) because I tried a complete copy pasted code to just see if it worked and the problem is with the header it cant find it or something because it gives these errors

Comment: "_halfdelay", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
  "_intrflush", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
  "_keypad", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
  "_nonl", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in Notes-6c61f2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64